# React native - object exists in state but is undefined when I try to access it

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to query an API to use the data in a react native app but am running into a problem with accessing data I store in the state. Basically, I am trying to access a markets object which is stored in the state. If I examine the state, I see the markets object is properly set. However, as soon as I try to do anything with the markets object, I encounter an error that says `Cannot read property 'markets' of null`.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this issue?

I included the code that causes the issue below. I appreciate any suggestions.

```
export default class cryptoTracker extends Component {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  this.opts = {
      baseUrl: 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1',
      apikey: 'APIKEY',
      apisecret: 'APISECRET',
    };
    this.updateMarkets();
  }


  updateMarkets(){
   axios.get(this.opts.baseUrl + '/public/getmarkets').then((response) => { 
        this.setState({'markets' : response.data.result});
        }
      ).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.name)
        console.log("Error");
      });

  }

 render() {
  console.log("The state is below");
  console.log(this.state);
//This line causes the issue
  console.log(this.state.markets);


     return(
     <View>
     </View>);
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('cryptoTracker', () => cryptoTracker);
```

Comment: Can you paste your console output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason is, you didn't define the `state` variable in `constructor`. Api call be **asynchronous** so when you get data and do `setState`, after that only `state` will be available (before that `state` will be `null`), render will get executed before that and when it will try to access the value `this.state.makers`, it is throwing the error:

> Cannot read property 'markets' of null

Changes:

**1.** Define the `state` object and define the `makers` inside that, like this:

```
constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
         makers: {}
     }
     this.opts = {
       baseUrl: 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1',
       apikey: 'APIKEY',
       apisecret: 'APISECRET',
     };
}
```

**2.** Use [componentDidMount](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) lifecycle method and do the api call inside that, like this:

```
componentDidMount(){
   this.updateMarkets();
}
```

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is
>   mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you
>   need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to
>   instantiate the network request. Setting state in this method will
>   trigger a re-rendering.

**3.** Name of the component must start with a uppercase letter, so use **CryptoTracker** instead of **cryptoTracker**.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I understand why the set must be set in the constructor but why must I set it directly instead of using the `setState` function? I thought you were supposed to never set state directly?

Comment: `setState` is used to update the `state` value, to assign the default value, define the `state` in `constructor`. Yes correct we should never set the `state` directly outside of the `constructor`, but `constructor` is used to initialise different value there we assign default values to state also :)